# Assign multiple values to a signal during 1 process

Tags: for-loop, vhdl

If you assign a value to a signal in a process, does it only become the correct value of the signal at the end of the process?
So there would be no point in assigning a value to a signal more than once per process, because the last assignment would be the only one that would be implemented, correct?

I'm a bit desperate because I'm trying to implement the booth algorithm in VHDL with signals and I can't get it baked. It wasn't a problem with variables, but signals make it all more difficult.

I tried a for loop, but that doesn't work because I have to update the values within the loop.

My next idea is a counter in the testbench.

Would be very thanksful for an idea!

my current Code look like this:

```
architecture behave of booth is
signal buffer_result1, buffer_result2, buffer_result3: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "0000"&b;
signal s: std_logic:= '0';
signal count1, count2: integer:=0;

begin

    
    assignment: process(counter) is
    begin
        if counter = "000" then
            buffer_result1 <= "0000"&b;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    
    add_sub: process(counter) is
    begin
        if counter <= "011" then
            if(buffer_result1(0) = '1' and s = '0') then
                buffer_result2 <= buffer_result1(7 downto 4)-a;
            else if (buffer_result1(0) = '0' and s = '1') then
                buffer_result2 <= buffer_result1(7 downto 4)+a;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    shift:process(counter) is
    begin
        if counter <= "011"
            buffer_result3(7) <= buffer_result2(7);
            buffer_result3(6 downto 0) <= buffer_result2(7 downto 1);
            s<= buffer_result3(0);
        else
            result<=buffer_result3;
        end if;
end behave;
```

Comment: Your code has other issues. Many signals are missing from the process sensitivity lists. for example, `b` is missing from `assignment` process and `buffer_result1`, `s` and `a` are missing from `add_sub` process. Your post indicates you might think that VHDL is a software language. It is not, it is a hardware description language. Do you have a diagram of the expected circuit before you wrote any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: that's correct. A signal's value will not update until the end of your process.

Long answer: A signal will only update when its assignment takes effect. Some signal assignments will use `after` and specify a time, making the transaction time explicit. Without an explicit time given, signals will update after the default "time-delta," an "instant" of simulation time that passes as soon as all concurrently executing statements at the given sim time have completed (e.g. a process). So your signals will hold their initial values until the process completes, at which point sim time moves forward one "delta," and the values update.

That does *not* mean that multiple signal assignment statements to the same signal don't accomplish anything in a process. VHDL will take note of all assignments, but of a series of assignments given with the same transaction time, only the *last* assignment will take effect. This can be used for a few tricky things, although I've encountered differences of opinion on how often they should be tried. For instance:

```
-- Assume I have a 'clk' coming in

signal pulse   : std_ulogic;
signal counter : unsigned(2 downto 0);

pulse_on_wrap : process(clk) is
begin
    clock : if rising_edge(clk):
        pulse   <= '0'; -- Default assignment to "pulse" is 0
        counter <= counter + 1; -- Counter will increment each clock cycle
        if counter = 2**3-1 then
            pulse <= '1'; -- Pulse high when the counter drops to 0 (after this cycle)
        end if;
    end if clock;
end process pulse_on_wrap;
```

Here, the typical behavior is to assign the value `'0'` to `pulse` on each clock cycle. But if `counter` hits its max value, there will be a following assignment to `pulse`, which will set it to `'1'` once simulation time advances. Because it comes after the `'0'` assignment and also has a "delta" transaction delay, it will override the earlier assignment. So this process will cause the signal `pulse`, fittingly, to go high for one cycle each time the counter wraps to zero and then drop the next - it's a pulse, after all! :^)

I provide that example only to illustrate the potential benefit of multiple assignments within a process, as you mention that in your question. I do *not* advise trying anything fancy with assignments until you're clear on the difference between variable assignment and signal assignment - and how that needs to be reflected in your code!

Try to think of things in terms of simulation time and *hardware* when it comes to signals. Everything is static until time moves forward, *then* you can handle the new values. It's a learning curve, but it'll happen! ;^)

Comment: did you intend the process to activate on all changes of `clk`, rather than use `rising_edge(clk)`? Also the comments are misleading. The counter is 4 bits, so wraps when `counter` = 15 (assuming rising_edge added). Pulse will be high when counter is 8, not 0.

Comment: Thanks - I was jumping into VHDL fresh off of Python and got a little forgetful in transition.